# Application pod deployment across different openshift clusters

Tags: openshift, jenkins-pipeline, openshift-origin, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

I have openshift 3.9 installed in one AWS region ohio. I have jenkins installed in it. I have a pipeline code in where it will take Java code from GitHub bind with jboss and deployed it in project test within the same cluster. It works fine and I'm able to access the app as pod is creating and app is also binding with jboss. Now I want to deploy this application across different clusters either within the same region or across different regions. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `oc` command line tool in your Jenkins pipeline to deploy it to a different cluster. For a related example, check the [Gitlab review apps example using an OpenShift cluster](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/review-apps-openshift/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml). It does something similar, where the CI pipeline deploys the required artifacts to an OpenShift cluster using oc and appropriate credentials.